# How to access google-services from react-native module for android?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-native-module

I am following [firebase set up tutorial for google sign in with android sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) and am making small react-native module for it available here [asq-react-native-google-sign-in](https://github.com/Asimetriq/asq-react-native-google-sign-in)

With android implementation, I stumbled upon an issue.

Firebase tutorial mentions this step

```
getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)
```

In short, what this does is grab a certain value from `google-services.json` file generated by firebase and turned into xml source when applying `google-services` dependency (all of this is described in linked guide).

I can't figure out a way how I can access this from my react native module, closest I got to was using

```
getReactApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string. default_web_client_id)
```

but `default_web_client_id` is not defined. By inspecting it in android studio `R` relates to my native module not main application, so no wonder that its undefined. Is there a way for me to access `R` of my main application?

**EDIT** I could probably add it to constructor of native module and pass it in from main application, but thats 1 more step for users, if possible I'd like to grab this value from within my module.

Comment: I think is related to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910744/react-native-access-strings-xml-from-inside-javascript-code